# What is some current and important research that surrounds algebraic curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, research

I'm looking into the current state of research concerning algebraic curves and anywhere they may crop up in important research. Does anyone have any recommendations of what to look into. References to papers, books or specific researchers would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Do you have any more specific aspects of algebraic curves you’re looking into? Algebraic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ are surfaces, so an answer to the question in its current state could be *anything* related to surfaces which might not be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for pure math? If not, try looking in to algebraic coding theory.